# Definition of LPCC

Tags: signal-analysis, lpc

would you please tell me what does LPCC exactly do?How can we calculate the coefficients of LPCC?
I need to know clearly what is it so i can implement it.
I dont know if i am asking this question correctly but whats the different between LPC and LPCC?do they even have any similarity that gives us the ability to talk about differences?
I taught calculating mfc coefficients  is a part of lpcc? right?
I would appreciate if you help me out with that :)

Comment: Someone help please?

Comment: Have you Googled it?

Comment: First of all, there is more than one thing called LPCC. 1) Linear Program with Linear Complementarity Constraints; and 2) Linear Predictive Cepstral Coefficients. Secondly, if you're looking for people to give you working code, you're in the wrong place.

Comment: @Phonon Thanks for your response, yes i googled it and i was confused thats why i asked it here, and no im not looking for the code, i just dont know what is the formula of Linear predictive cepstral coefficient... so i can  implement it myself,as i said in my first question.